# EigenVector I don't understand

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know how to calculate the eigenvalues and get eigenvectors but there are some Matrix I don't understand?

[image]

[image]

When Eigenvalue is $1$ we have two eigenvectors i understand and have don gauss-eleminationsand only get $(1,0,1)$ when I have done Gauss-Eleminations  but where does $(0,1,0)$ comes from?

[image]

And here is the Matrix above picture:

You can divide the middle row with $1/3$ so you get $(1,0,1)$
and remove the upper and bottom row but where does the eigenvector $(0,1,0)$ comes from
and how two vectors span this eigenspace I don't understand??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to understand eigenvectors is to look at the definition of eigenvectors:

$M\underline{v}=\lambda\underline{v}$ where $M$ is the matrix and $\underline{v}$ the eigenvector and $\lambda$ the associated eigenvalue.

So what I am guessing you are doing is that you rearranged the equation a bit and got the following $(M-\lambda I)\underline{v}=\underline{0}$. So looking at the matrix you got at the end you need to find vectors that gives you the zero vector and looking at it if you have the matrix operating on $(0,1,0)$ you get $(0,0,0)$ so everything is in order. And thus $(0,1,0)$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: Can you explain more @DragonFire0310 i don't understand but i know where the equations?

Comment: So you understand $Mv = \lambda v$ correct and that you can rearrange that into $Mv-\lambda v=0$ and then to "factor" out to get $(M-\lambda I)v = 0$. You already did $M -\lambda I$ so what you need to do now is to "guess" with intuition a vector $v$ which gives you the zero vector when you do the operation $Mv$, this works for me with 2x2 and 3x3 matrices, for higher dim matrices you have to do row operations to find the null space. Is it now clearer ? @Jonte YH

Comment: Okay i have done the calculations on that but how can you know when there is a vector that is missing then? @DragonFire0310

Comment: So you want to know how many eigenvectors there are for each eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes @DragonFire0310 ?

Comment: Alright, the easiest way I know of is that you do $M-\lambda I$ and then you look at the rank of the new matrix and then with the rank-nullity theorem you know the nullity of the new matrix. The nullity = number of linear independent eigenvectors which you should get for the eigenvalue.

Comment: Yes Thanks @DragonFire0310 but how do you apply this formula (M−λI)v=0 i know I is the Identity Matrix but i'dont get 0 when i multiply with the other vector (1,0,1)?

Comment: When i take M x eigenvector then i get 0 in both cases with both eigenvectors?

Comment: $0$ is the origin or the zero vector with all entries being zero, so in a sense what you want to find is the null space of the matrix $M-\lambda I$

Comment: No, when $M$ is operating on $v$ you should get $\lambda v$

Comment: What is M in this case @DragonFire0310?

Comment: Your matrix where you want to find the eigenvalues for.

Comment: But in this case if we take lamda*v where v is the eigenvector we have 1*1+ 0*1+1*1=2
But M*v = 0 is zero?
-6*1 + 0*0 +6*!
etc? @@DragonFire0310

Comment: I think you confuse the matrices $M$ is the first matrix and $M-\lambda I$ is the second matrix which you gave. $M$ operating on $v$ should give $\lambda v$ and if you operate $M-\lambda I$ on $v$ you should get $0$.

Comment: Okay hahaha Thanks


Answer (score 1):

The row reduced form is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The null space of this matrix is
$$\{(x_3, x_2, x_3) : x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{x_2(0, 1, 0) + x_3(1, 0, 1) : x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}\} = \text{span}\{(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)\}.$$
Since row operations don't change the null space of a matrix, this is the null space of the original matrix.